# How to know which all on-premises machines were earlier or so far have been replicated using a particular Config Server?

Tags: azure, configserver, server-migration, azure-site-recovery

I want to know all the servers which have been in past replicated using a particular Config Server and later on removed from replication? I can easily see which all servers are currently being replicated but I want to know the servers which were kept on replication and removed midway, I want list of those servers. Preferably through Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only option is to review the activity logs. Go back to 90 days and see which servers were removed from replication.

Comment: Yes, but this we can have a check for servers within last 90 days only. Whats about from scratch (since beginning) ?

Comment: No other option. You may leave feedback for this feature request at - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/256299-site-recovery